# React Native navigate on button press

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native, an I am wanting to navigate to a new page on a button press.  I have created my own custom button for reuse between screens.

```
export default class NormalButton extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={this.props.onPress}
            >
            <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.text}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
}
```

I want to call this button in my main class and then navigate to another screen when the button is clicked.

```
export default class Home extends Component {

static route = {
    navigationBar: {
        title: 'Home',
    }
}

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

onTestPress = () => {
    this.props.navigator.push('page2');
}

render() {
    return(
        <NormalButton 
            text="test"
            onPress={this.onTestPress}
        />
    );
}
}
```

When i do this, I get a warning saying "cannot update during an existing state transition"  Also, if I take out the `onPress` from my `Home` class and just place it in the `NormalButton` class, it activates the `onPress` immediately when the app starts and goes to the next screen

Comment: When you do it like the above code, you get a warning, but does it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use arrow binding in the props like this.

`onPress={() => this.onTestPress()}`

Answer (score 0):

Stack navigator is the easiest way to navigate between pages. Please have a look at a below link.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html